# changing price based on option jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to change the price based on whatever is been selected from the options... I don't know how to be able to do it. In my example, I want to change the car price based on the car brand, car model, and car engine. after the user has chosen all the option the car price will appear as the value on HTML.

Thanks in advance.

```js
 var carPri = $("#carPri h4").val();
 var monPay = parseFloat($("#monPay").val());
 var fnum= 0.2 * carPri / 10 +"%";
 var snum = 0.8 * carPri;
 var aft = carPri - snum;


function calc(){
  var result = carPri - snum;
  $("#doPa h1").text(result +" USD");
}
$("#doPa input").keyup(calc);


function carBrand(){
var brand = $("#brand").val();

if(brand == "BMW") {
 $(".bmwMo").css("display","block");
 $(".tesMo").css("display","none");
 $(".ferrMo").css("display","none");
} else if(brand == "Ferrari"){
 $(".bmwMo").css("display","none");
 $(".tesMo").css("display","none");
 $(".ferrMo").css("display","block");
} else if (brand == "Tesla"){
 $(".bmwMo").css("display","none");
 $(".tesMo").css("display","block");
 $(".ferrMo").css("display","none");
}
}

$("#brand").change(carBrand);

function carModel(){
 var model = $("#model").val();
 if (model == "x1") {
  $("#carImg img").css("display","block");
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/x.png");
 }else if (model == "740li") {
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/bmw740li.png");
 }else if (model == "320i") {
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/bmw320i.png");
 }

 else if (model == "488 Pista") {
  $("#carImg img").css("display","block");
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/pista.png");
 }else if (model == "F8 Tributo") {
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/tributo.png");
 }else if (model == "Portofino") {
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/portofino.png");
 }

 else if (model == "Model S") {
  $("#carImg img").css("display","block");
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/models.png");
 }else if (model == "Model 3") {
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/model3.png");
 }else if (model == "Model X") {
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/modelx.png");
 }

}
$("#model").change(carModel);

function carEng(){
 var engine = $("#engine").val();

 if (engine == "Petrol") {
   model == "x1"
   $("#carPri h4").text("8000 USD");

 }else if (engine == "Petrol") {
  model == "740li"
  $("#carPri h4").text("8500 USD");
 }
}

$("#engine").change(carEng);

/*
function carModel(){
 var model = $("#model").val();
 var carImg = $("#carImg").val();
  var engine = $("#engine").val();

 if (model == "X1") {
  if (engine == "Petrol") {
   $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/x.png");
           carPri = 80000;
  }else if (model == "740li") {
   if (engine == "Petrol") {
    $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/bmw740li.png");
    carPri = 90000;
   }
  }else if (model == "320i") {
   if (engine == "Petrol") {
    $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/bmw320i.png");
    carPri = 60000;
   }
  }
 } else if (model == "X1") {
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/x.png");
  if (engine == "Diesel") {
   carPri = 75000;
  }else if (model=="740li") {
   $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/bmw740li.png");
   if (engine == "Diesel"){
    carPri = 85000;
   } 
  }else if (model == "320i") {
   $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/bmw320i.png");
   if (engine == "Diesel"){
    carPri = 55000;
   }
 
  }
 } else if (model == "488 Pista") {
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/pista.png");
  if (engine == "Petrol") {
          carPri = 1000000;
  }else if (model == "F8 Tributo") {
   $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/tributo.png");
   if (engine == "Petrol") {
    carPri = 1500000;
   }
  }else if (model == "Portofino") {
   $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/portofino.png");
   if (engine == "Petrol") {
    carPri = 2050000;
   }
  }
 } else if (model == "488 Pista") {
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/pista.png");
  if (engine == "Diesel") {
   carPri = 990000;
  }else if (model=="F8 Tributo") {
   $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/tributo.png");
   if (engine == "Diesel") {
    carPri = 1450000;
   }
   
  }else if (model == "Portofino") {
   $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/portofino.png");
   if (engine == "Diesel"){
    carPri = 2000000;
   } 
  }
  } else if (model == "Model S") {
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/models.png");
  if (engine == "Petrol") {
          carPri = 800000;
  }else if (model == "Model 3") {
   $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/model3.png");
   if (engine == "Petrol") {
    carPri = 700000;
   }
  }else if (model == "Model X") {
   $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/modelx.png");
   if (engine == "Petrol") {
    carPri = 750000;
   }
  }
 } else if (model == "Model S") {
  $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/models.png");
  if (engine == "Diesel") {
   carPri = 795000;
  }else if (model=="Model 3") {
   $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/model3.png");
   if (engine == "Diesel") {
    carPri = 695000;
   }
   
  }else if (model == "Model X") {
   $("#carImg img").attr("src","img/modelx.png");
   if (engine == "Diesel"){
    carPri = 745000;
   } 
  }
 }

 
}

$("#model").change(carModel);
*/

function month (){
   var downPay = parseFloat($("#downPay").val());
 if (monPay == "12") {
  var be = aft * 0.1;
 }else if (monPay == "24") {
  var be = aft * 0.2;
 }else if (monPay == "36") {
  var be = aft * 0.3;
 }
 var resultMon = parseFloat(aft + be);
 $("#result").text(resultMon +" USD");
 console.log(resultMon);
}

$("#result").change(month);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <div>
      <label>Brand</label>
      <select id="brand">
         <option disabled selected>Select The Brand</option>
         <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
         <option value="Ferrari">Ferrari</option>
         <option value="Tesla">Tesla</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div >
      <label>Model</label>
      <select id="model">
         <option disabled selected>Select The Model</option>
         <option class="bmwMo" value="x1">X1</option>
         <option class="bmwMo" value="740li">740li</option>
         <option class="bmwMo" value="320i">320i </option>
         <option class="ferrMo" value="488 Pista">488 Pista</option>
         <option class="ferrMo" value="F8 Tributo">F8 Tributo</option>
         <option class="ferrMo" value="Portofino">Portofino</option>
         <option class="tesMo" value="Model S">Model S</option>
         <option class="tesMo" value="Model 3">Model 3</option>
         <option class="tesMo" value="Model X">Model X</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div id="carImg">
      <img alt="car image">
   </div>
   <div>
      <label>Engine</label>
      <select id="engine">
         <option disabled selected>Select The Model</option>
         <option>Petrol</option>
         <option>Diesel</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div id="carPri">
      <label>Price</label>
      <h4></h4>
   </div>
   <div id="doPa">
      <label>Down Payment</label>
      <input type="text" name="downPayment" id="downPay">
      <input type="text" name="downPayment" id="doPayPer">
      <h1></h1>
   </div>
   <div id="monPay">
      <label>Month Payment</label>
      <select>
         <option disabled selected>Select Month Payment </option>
         <option value="12">12</option>
         <option value="24">24</option>
         <option value="36">36</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function carEng() {
  var engine = $('#engine').val();

  if (engine == 'Petrol') {
    model == 'x1';
    $('#carPri h4').text('8000 USD');
  } else if (engine == 'Diesel') {
    model == '740li';
    $('#carPri h4').text('8500 USD');
  }
}
```

Seems you forgot to check for 'Diesel' 
However i not see logic for model and brand to affect price calculation